# how to put logo in bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put logo in bootstrap navbar but issue that the logo is bigger than the navbar so i want the logo to be responsive and fit nicely in the navbar.  I have tried every trick i could find but still the image is large.  Please help
here is master page:

```
<body>
     <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <%--<img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt=""/>--%>
                    <img src="img/chs.jpg"" alt=""/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Logo Nav by Start Bootstrap</h1>
                <p>Note: You may need to adjust some CSS based on the size of your logo. The default logo size is 150x50 pixels.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->

    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

my css file

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

.navbar-fixed-top .nav {
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 100px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
        padding: 15px 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/2YrBFFYHn1 nothing wrong in bootply, what size is your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 5px;
}
.navbar-brand img {
    max-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6L65j2sv/

Answer (score 1):

You could do media queries to change the size of it, for example:

```
@media(max-width: 768px;) {
    .navbar-brand img { width: 100px; height: 75px; }
}
```

and so forth for the different sizes you are targeting.

Additionally, you could also get a little fancier, and instead of having an `<img />` tag within `.navbar-brand`, you could set the background of it with something like this:

```
.navbar-brand img { width: 200px; height: 125px; background-image: url(../img/my-logo.png); }
```

and that would allow you to change the actual image with media queries, for example:

```
@media(max-width: 768px;) {
    .navbar-brand img { width: 100px; height: 75px; background-image: url(../img/my-logo-small.png); }
}
```